# Convert data.table with one id and one variable column to presence matrix

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

I have a data.table with the following structure:

```
num_id  value
1000    A1
1001    A1
1000    A2
1000    A3
1001    A54
1002    A55
1001    A100
```

and would like to turn it into a dt of the form

```
num_id A1        A2       A3       A54       A55       A100
1000   1         1        1        0         0         0
1001   1         0        0        1         0         1
1002   0         0        0        0         1         0
```

I thought this would be easy using `dcast`. The formula that came to mind was `dcast(dt, numid~value)` However that complained with `Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 4850158203 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647`. This is more than the number of expected rows, because I have about 500,000 unique IDs. After running tests on a smaller datatable it appears the call to `dcast` is keeping the IDs exactly as they are, replacing the value column by a vector of columns where only 1 element is not null. That is not helping much since the essential aggregation/grouping step is missing.

I wrote the following code, which works but is slow and convoluted. Is there a way to do this in a single dcast call?

```
futurecolumns=unique(dt$value)
aggregated=dt[,list(list(value)), by=num_id]
out=t(sapply(aggregated$V1, function(x){futurecolumns %in% x}))
out=as.data.table(out*1)
out$num_id=aggregated$num_id
setnames(out, c(futurecolumns, "num_id"))
```

Comment: What about `dcast(unique(dt), num_id ~ value, fun.aggregate=length)` ?

Comment: It looks like the `unique` in your suggestion is there to remove duplicate rows in `dt`? That's not the issue, there are no dups AFAIK. This gives me the exact same error and behaviour, namely that the resulting df has a line for every combination of `num_id` and `value`, whereas I want a df that has as many rows as there are unique  values in `num_id`.

Comment: ~500,000 unique `num_id`s * 9700 unique `value`s  = 4,850,000,000 values in a grid. That's not going to work out well for anybody. Maybe a sparse matrix instead since you will have so many 0's?

Comment: There are only about ~500 unique `value`s, so the final df should be of dimension 500,000x500.

Answer (score 1):

One way would to be to `count` number of rows for `num_id` and `value` and use `pivot_wider` :

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  count(num_id, value) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, 
                     values_fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  num_id    A1    A2    A3   A54   A55  A100
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   1000     1     1     1     0     0     0
#2   1001     1     0     0     1     0     1
#3   1002     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

---

In base R you can use `aggregate` :

```
futurecolumns=unique(dt$value)
aggregate(value~num_id, dt, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = futurecolumns)))
```

Comment: oh right! I was so deep in reshape and DT methods that I didn't think of aggregate! Thanks.

Comment: When I try running the `dplyr` version, I also get an error:
`Error: Can't assign to elements that don't exist. ✖ Locations 413590, 827179, 1240768, 1654357, 2067946, etc. don't exist. ℹ There are only 1 element.` Additionally, some warnings: `Warning message in nrow * ncol: “NAs produced by integer overflow”Warning message in nrow * (val_id$col - 1L): “NAs produced by integer overflow”Warning message in val_id$row + nrow * (val_id$col - 1L):“NAs produced by integer overflow”`. Seems like the df is just too large?

Comment: @ArthurGilly Does base R method work fine? Do you have some other columns which is not shown? If that is the case, you can `select` the required columns before using `pivot_wider`.

Comment: no, it seems to create a data frame with 2 columns, the second containing nested lists/tables. The method by @hello_friend also using `aggregate` works. I don't have additional columns in the df.

Comment: @ArthurGilly If you store the output of `aggregate` in a variable `temp <- aggregate(value~num_id, dt, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = futurecolumns)))` you can then do `do.call(data.frame, temp)` to get as separate columns.

Comment: Yes that works, and is both faster than @hello_friend 's answer and slower than my original code that uses `%in%`.

Answer (score 1):

Base R one obfuscated expression:

```
aggregate(. ~ num_id,
          data.frame(num_id = df$num_id,
                     +sapply(unique(df$value), `==`, df$value)), sum)
```

Comment: Thanks! this works but is slower (`microbenchmark`, 100 repeats) than both my snippet above and @Ronak 's base R solution.

Comment: @ArthurGilly no worries, Ronak is a gun, and one of the best R programmers in the world so his solutions are always pretty darn good. For my own practise I try to offer additional solutions that display different (generally base R) approaches to problems. Unfortunately, this was the best I could do. Hopefully the equality test in the sapply function and conversion from a boolean to integer matrix offered something useful to you and to others.